# Visual Studio 2015 not compiling .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I downloaded a tutorial a couple of days ago, and the instructor in it compiled a program which I canot seem to compile. I have followed the exact same steps as he does but in the end I am left with the same error. I am pretty sure the error is not from my code, and it is from some unchecked function in visual studio. This is my error:

**"C:\Users\tripl\Desktop\Rock...paper...carbon\Work\VisualStudio\C++\Section_02\Debug\BullCowGame.exe" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

This is my code:

```
int Main()

{

   return 0;

}
```

Now I fiddled around a bit and what I could deduce was that this error only happens when I start an empty project from the selection menu itself. If I donot start with an empty project, I have the `#include stdafx.h` namespaces and so on, I do not encounter this problem. I have a faint idea of what the error is but I can't understand why this error happens only when I start an empty project. There are few answers on the web suggesting something wrong with the path but I double checked it within Visual Studio and everything seems to be alright. In order for VS to compile this program is it essential that the code must contain `#inlcude stdafx.h`? The instructor in the tutorial didnot use this and he created a new file within the source directory.

EDIT: User Abhineet has pointed out the answer. Code should have started with

```
int main()
```

Comment: Is it `Main` or `main`?

Comment: @Abhineet random internet stranger, this is so embarrassing. I've solved my problem. Thank you for reminding me in the world of programming the solution is always in hindsight. The code should contain 'main' but my code had 'Main'.

Comment: That happens to the best of us. Solution are always within our hand's reach :) I will post this as answer then.

Comment: "In order for VS to compile this program is it essential that the code must contain #inlcude stdafx.h" No. Also, it's `#include` - as you just learned, compilers are very picky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Main` should be `main`. Mind the mighty `M`.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point),

In C and C++, the function prototype of the main function looks like one of the following:

```
int main(void);
int main();

int main(int argc, char **argv);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);



// more specifically in C
// NOT according to the ISO C standard 5.1.2.2.1
// BUT in embedded programming depending on the µC, this form is also used
void main (void);
```

May be you are coming from `C#` background or it might be a silly typo mistake.